# iOS App Store ExecutionEngineException attempting to JIT compile

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, app-store, mvvm-light, jit

I have a really awkward problem. I have build my app for iOS and tested it on all emulators and it works fine. I have installed it on a device (iPhone 6 plus) and that works fine as well. However, when I submit it to the app store, the feedback is that it crashes on launch on all devices. The crash log attached shows this error;

```
Unhandled Exception:
    System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger:get_Default ()' while running with --aot-only. See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.
```

The code that causes this error is in ViewWillAppear;

```
Messenger.Default.Register<LoggedInFailedMessage>(this, LoginFailed);
Messenger.Default.Register<LoggedInMessage>(this, LoggedIn);
```

The below stack overflow thread seems to indicate it might be caused by using value types, but I am using reference types.

[System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method only in Debug Mode on device (MonoTouch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837517/system-executionengineexception-attempting-to-jit-compile-method-only-in-debug)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! I don't know how I can test for these errors if they work when i debug on emulator and device but fail when apple test it.

Answer (score 0):

Most of those issues where fixed a long time ago. Make sure your options for the **AppStore** builds (or the one you used to submit) match the one you're testing (e.g. **Debug** builds).

In particular make sure that the **Enable generic value type sharing** options is **ON** on the build you are submitting. This will include some extra code to ensure all value types code path variants are available at runtime.

Note that this setting should already be **ON** by default. Still it's a good practice to ensure your debugging/release settings are *mostly* (except debugging stuff) identical. Otherwise you risk testing different code, locally, than what you're submitting to the store.

Comment: What has resolved it is to make sure i use 'Link All Assemblies' instead of the 'SDK Only' option. The frustrating thing is that whenever I change options such as LLVM, thumb2 instruction set etc, it toggles the Linker option and overwrites what I set it as. I basically had to toggle things on and off in order to get it to stay on 'Link All'. Now I just need to try cutting the size down from 30mb!

Comment: This issue has raised it's head again when trying to add updates to the app. Only this time, the "Link All Assemblies" is the option that will not work and the others do. :-/