# Xamarin iOS AdHoc Error attempting to JIT compile

Tags: xamarin, mvvm-light

I have an app built using the AdHoc profile and deploying to my phone. I have all options ticked (LLVM, Thumb-2, Generic value type sharing). If I use the Linker option of "Dont Link" then it deploys to the device fine and works.

If I use "Link All Assemblies", which I will have to do when deploying the app to the store, I get a JIT error with some MVVMLight code I am using.

Does anyone know why this is? I have experienced issues like this before ([iOS App Store ExecutionEngineException attempting to JIT compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123471/ios-app-store-executionengineexception-attempting-to-jit-compile)) but they always were resolved by using "Link All Assemblies".

This app is on the store and has been working fine (unified API). I am just adding some updates and want to test it. I have had to update xamarin as well.

The exact error is:

```
"Unhandled managed exception:
Attempting to JIT compile method 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger:get_Default ()' while running with --aot-only. See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.
(System.ExecutionEngineException)"
```

Using "Link SDK Assemblies Only" works fine on the device in AdHoc as well.

Thanks for any pointers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked around this by using "Link SDK Assemblies Only". In the past, it created an IPA so large using this option that I could not submit it to the app store, however now it has only increased the size by a couple of MB.

Also "Include Artwork" needed to be unchecked to be able to submit to the app store.